# React-Mapbox-GL drastically slows down whole app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to build an App using ReactJS and React-Mapbox-GL.

I have one component which has some content that has a typing animation using react-typing-animation.

After this, I have a Map Component, but as soon as I import this component into my App, the whole app and browser now run extremely slow.

I have no errors, only (mostly) timeout warnings. Screenshot below.

[image: Console Errors]

I've searched through Google for a few hours but unfortunately found nothing. The code below is provided by react-mapbox-gl's npm install page.

MapSection Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactMapboxGl, { Layer, Feature } from "react-mapbox-gl";
const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
    accessToken: "myaccesstoken"
  });



export class MapSection extends Component {


    render() {

        return( 
            <div>
                <Map
                style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
                containerStyle={{
                    height: "100vh",
                    width: "100vh"
                }}>
                    <Layer
                    type="symbol"
                    id="marker"
                    layout={{ "icon-image": "marker-15" }}>
                    <Feature coordinates={[-0.481747846041145, 51.3233379650232]}/>
                    </Layer>
                </Map>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Expecting for the map to work (which it sort of does), but without slowing my App(And Browser) down to a snail's pace.

*** UPDATE ***
When I take out my animated Typing Component, the map works fine. So it somehow is clashing with react-typing-animation, and breaking the App

Comment: Works fine in a sandbox for me, is this all your code?

Comment: At this point, I only have one other component. You can see it here - https://gitlab.mi.hdm-stuttgart.de/eo023/react-map-cv/tree/master/src/components